# Как выставить непрозрачность Canvas'а в Python 3?

Tags: python

## Как выставить непрозрачность канваса "c"?.

```
from tkinter import *
import keyboard

def pause():
   print("pause")
keyboard.add_hotkey('esc', pause)

aphunt=Tk()
aphunt.geometry("800x600")
aphunt.title("game")
c=Canvas(width=800,height=600, background='blue')
c.pack()
aphunt.mainloop()
```

Comment: опишите проблему более подробно. что сейчас и что вам требуется.

Comment: Непрозрачность=фиксированный цвет, так что просто закрасьте канвас

Answer (score 0):

Непрозрачность=какой-то фиксированный цвет/рисунок:

```
c.create_rectangle(0, 0, 800,600,fill="black")
```

например.

Comment: Nezerix, спасибо!

Comment: @Manerlock можете тогда отметить ответ полезным и принять решение, пожалуйста!